# Android custom actionbar overlay

Tags: android

So i have been following the tutorials on the android developer website. i have created an android project with min SDK of 8, and included the compatibility for the android 2.1  for the menu bar. i am able to get the menu bar to work properly for android 4.0 and 2.2, no issues.

now i am trying to set the overlay for the menubar, and i ran into an  issue. while setting up a custom theme with the parent being an AppCompact theme, as stated here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html .

the code with the issue is :

```
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

2 issues arise:

> error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name '@android:style/  Theme.AppCompat'.

and

> android:windowActionBarOverlay requires API level 11 (current min is
>   8)

the first issue, i have no idea why it is being thrown. i use Theme.AppCompact in my manifest and it works. the 2nd issue is confusing me, in the google tutorials it states to include both definitions, as one is for android devices with the new API and the other is for older API's.

i have tried to clean/build my project, it did not help.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by replacing

```
parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

with

```
 parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```